# How to extend makefile to compose library?

Tags: c, compilation, makefile, static-libraries

I have a makefile which does what I want with the compilation but I want it also to make a library instead of only object files.

```
CC=gcc
CFLAGS=-g -Wall
DEPS = tree.h
OBJ = main.o tree.o 

%.o: %.c $(DEPS)
    $(CC) -c -o $@ $< $(CFLAGS)

tree: $(OBJ)
    $(CC) -o $@ $^ $(CFLAGS)

clean:
    rm -f *.o tree
```

Now I want the makefile to be something like this:

```
gcc -Wall -g -c tree.c
ar -r libtree.a tree.o
gcc main.c -o main -ltree -L.
./main
```

What I have to add to my existing makefile?

Comment: ok I will try to improve my rate, but if you know the answer please help me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should do what you want:

```
%.o: %.c $(DEPS)
    $(CC) -c -o $@ $< $(CFLAGS)

lib%.a: %.o
    ar -r $@ $^

main: $(OBJ) $(DEPS:%.h=lib%.a)
    $(CC) -o $@ $^ $(CFLAGS) $(DEPS:%.h=-l%) -L.
```

Note that this only works in GNU Make (in particular, the `%` in `$(DEPS:%.h=lib%.a)` is a GNU-specific extension).

Comment: this will create a library from any .o file

Comment: @EarlGray yeah, I figured that it was what the OP wanted. Limiting it to `libtree.a` is much simpler :)